# After printing influence() results from metafor package, how do I get a line number for each entry?

Tags: r

I am conducting a meta-analysis. I am using the `influence()` command for outlier detection.

So what I did is the following:

```
outlier1 <- influence(result)
print(outlier1)
```

This gives me 250 entries indicating whether a study has to be excluded. Then I have to delete outlier studies by indicating the row. And here's the thing: I have 250 studies, and I don't want to count the rows manually in order to know which studies to exclude.

Here's what the result looks like:

```
Study Indicator_1 Indicator_N Outlier?
------------------------------------

(250 entries)
```

Now I would like to know how I can alter the printed result such that it looks like:

```
Number Study Indicator_1 Indicator_N Outlier?
--------------------------------------------
```

Counting should optimally start at 1.

---

Here is the data and code-sequence required for creating a reproducible example:

Data: http://www.filedropper.com/metadaten

Code sequence:

```
install.packages("xlsx")
install.packages("metafor")
library(xlsx)
library(metafor)

input <-read.xlsx("C:/Users/feal/Documents/BA_MA/Data/01. ID FP/meta_daten.xlsx", sheetName="input")

## View(input)

result <-rma(yi=zcor, vi=var, data=input, 
   measure="GEN", method="REML", level=95,
   slab=paste(author, pub_date, sep=", "))

print(result)

outlier1 <- influence(result)
print(outlier1)
```

---

After that I get the following results, a star on the right indicates that the outlier has to be removed.

[image]

Remove function as for an example:

```
input_out1 <-input[-19,]
print(input_out1)
```

I just want every column to have an entry number. ***Or every entry to be removed, where there is a star on the right.***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it myself.

If you are able convert the results such that the `View()` function can be used, above the console window in RStudio, the results will be shown with a line number prefix.

This is what made it work:

```
outputText <-capture.output(influence(result))

outputFrame = data.frame(outputText)

View(outputFrame)
```

Regards,
Feal

Comment: I've edited your question to include this information (which is what you should have done in the first place ...)

Comment: I deleted the redundant content and added the solution where it should belong :).

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(name=infl$dfbs$slab,
       rstu=infl[["is.infl"]])%>%filter(rstu==T)
```

Maybe this is all you need. You can modify the dataframe by looking at the output list of influence()